# how do local tasks avoid garbage collection before they are completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am interested to know how is the lifetime of tasks managed when calling asynchronous methods
and storing the tasks returned in local variables. Consider this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();

        var task = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(@"http:\\www.rpmglobal.com"));
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            try
            {
                this.textBox.Text = t.Result;
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                this.textBox.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());      
    }
}
```

the variable `task` is a local variable that should become available for garbage collection as soon as the method exits which can be long before the task completes. What is the mechanism to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: variables don't become available for garbage collection. The *objects* that reference variables *refer to* may.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever `DownloadStringTaskAsync` is doing, at some later point in time, it's got to be able to set the `Result` for the `Task` that it returned, and mark it as complete. Logically, therefore, it must have a reference to this `Task` object also (the reference may be via a chain of references or it may be a direct reference)

Comment: Well, either that, or `Task` has a reference to some other object that it checks when reading the `Result` property and when calling `ContinueWith`. In that case, the `Task` object itself may be garbage collected, but that's not a problem, as nothing uses it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there´s a thread running.
Running threads are not gc´ed
(if this would be the case, the garbage collector
could end your main anytime)